# Why aren't my media queries responding?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my media breaks to work as expected. I would like to have a similar results to Bootstrap's grid system as follows:

- First case: When the width is equal or greater than 992px:

  > Three identical col-4 type columns containing the different paragraphs
- Second case: When the width is between 768px and 991px:

  > Two identical col-6 columns, with the third one being a col-12 type column (obviously below the two).
- Third case: When the width is equal or less than 767px:

  > Three identical col-12 type columns stacked one over the other.

I'm having more trouble than I should getting the breaks to work, but I don't know for the life of me where I'm going wrong.

Here's my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Our Menu</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    /***Base Styles***/
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 1.5px;
      background-color: beige;
    }
    .restaurant {
      margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 70px;
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    h2 {
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 2px solid black;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      width: 180px;
    }
    p {
      padding: 35px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
    #meal1,
    #meal2,
    #meal3 {
      background-color: khaki;
      border: 2px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .meal1 {
      background-color: #F4C2C2;
    }
    .meal2 {
      background-color: #B22222;
    }
    .meal3 {
      background-color: grey;
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      #meal1 {
        width: 32%;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 25px;
      }
      #meal2 {
        width: 32%;
        float: left;
      }
      #meal3 {
        width: 32%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
      }
    }
    /***Tablet Styles***/
    @media (min-width: 768) and (max-width: 991px) {
      #meal1 {
        width: 48.46%;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      #meal2 {
        width: 48.46%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      #meal3 {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
      }
    }
    /***Mobile Styles***/
    @media (max-width: 767) {
      #meal1,
      #meal2,
      #meal3 {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="restaurant">
    <h1>Our Menu</h1>
    <div class="meals">
      <div id="meal1">
        <h2 class="meal1">Smoked Fish</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et tellus dictum, accumsan nunc sit amet, porttitor turpis. Phasellus orci felis, accumsan eu cursus ac, venenatis non massa. Mauris eget nisi pellentesque, luctus quam a, lacinia augue.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="meal2">
        <h2 class="meal2">Spicy Coppa</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et tellus dictum, accumsan nunc sit amet, porttitor turpis. Phasellus orci felis, accumsan eu cursus ac, venenatis non massa. Mauris eget nisi pellentesque, luctus quam a, lacinia augue.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="meal3">
        <h2 class="meal3">Fregola Salda</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et tellus dictum, accumsan nunc sit amet, porttitor turpis. Phasellus orci felis, accumsan eu cursus ac, venenatis non massa. Mauris eget nisi pellentesque, luctus quam a, lacinia augue.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [a validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). Your CSS has machine detectable errors in it.

> ```
> @media (min-width: 768) and (max-width: 991px) {
> ```

You have repeatedly (although not universally) specified a non-zero length without a unit. This renders the CSS invalid so it will be ignored.

Comment: Oh bloody hell. How on earth did I miss that? Now I see the importance of validators. Thank you @Quentin!